# Determining the matrix of the form AX

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning

[image]

I want to solve problem b)
Here is my solution:

I followed the hint and found the column space of matrix $A$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\-1 & 1\\0 &-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Equation $Ax = b$ has solution only if $b$ is in **column space**(we can express b as a linear combination of the columns of matrix $A$).

But i don't know what to do next. How can I find an answer on question b)?

**Edited:** the answer is
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a matrix $B$ is of the form of $B=AX$, then

$$B=A \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}Ax_1 & Ax_2 & Ax_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence the columns of $B$ must be in the column space of $A$.

Note that

$$span \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \right) =  span\left( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \right)=\left\{ a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} +d \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}: a, d \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!I also thought about this, but the answer has another form. How did we come to the result above(i added to the original post)?

Comment: updated my answer.